# How to create a new TextField with a label above

Tags: java, javafx

I started to work on a project in Java.
I wish to create a control in JavaFX similar to TextField but with a label at the top left corner.
additionally, The textfield contains a SimpleBooleanProperty to indicate if the user typed a valid String based on regular expression.

i tried to extend Textfield and to add a label as his child, but the label created inside the TextField.

Here is the code for CustomTF

```
package OrderPackage;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class CustomTF extends ValidationTextField {
    
    
    private Label desc = new Label();
    private Timeline animation = new Timeline();
    
    
    public CustomTF() {
        this("");
    }
    
    
    public CustomTF(String promptText) {
        
//      this.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        
        this.setPromptText(promptText);
        desc.setOpacity(0);
        desc.textProperty().bind(this.promptTextProperty());

        this.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, old, news) -> {
            
            if (news) {
                animation.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0), new KeyValue(desc.opacityProperty(), 0)), 
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(desc.opacityProperty(), 1)), 
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0), new KeyValue(desc.layoutYProperty(), this.getLayoutY())),
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(desc.layoutYProperty(), this.getLayoutY() - 25)));
            }
            
            else {
                animation.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0), new KeyValue(desc.opacityProperty(), 1)), 
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(desc.opacityProperty(), 0)), 
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0), new KeyValue(desc.layoutYProperty(), this.getLayoutY() - 25)),
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(250), new KeyValue(desc.layoutYProperty(), this.getLayoutY())));
            }
            
            animation.play();
            animation.getKeyFrames().clear();
        });
        
        this.getChildren().addAll(desc);
        
    }
    
    public Label getLabelPromptText() {
        return desc;
    }


}
```

Here is the code for ValidationTextField

```
package OrderPackage;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ValidationTextField extends TextField{
    
    private SimpleBooleanProperty validationProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private Validation validationRule;
    

    public ValidationTextField() {
        this(Validation.ANY);
    }
    
    public ValidationTextField(Validation validationRule) {
        super();
        this.validationRule = validationRule;
        
    }
    
    public void setValidationRule(Validation validationRule) {
        this.validationRule = validationRule;
    }
    
    public boolean validate() {
        return this.getText().trim().matches(validationRule.getValidation());
    }
    

    public SimpleBooleanProperty validationProperty() {
        return validationProperty;
    }
    
    public String getValidation() {
        return validationRule.getValidation();
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: this question is waaayyy too broad: what you need is a custom skin .. and/or search for third-party controls that support validation (and its visualization), then either use those or learn about options to implement what you want.

Comment: Make your new node extend `VBox`. Add the `Label` and `TextField`.